# Ruby regular expressions: negative matching

Tags: ruby, regex

I was wondering if it was possible to use negative matching on whole words, so that something like `[^(<em>.*?<\/em>)]` would match **everything but** text between (and including) `<em>...</em>`.

I was thinking about using negative lookahead, but I don't think this will work, as I need to check for the opening `<em>` as well.

Of course, I could just use the positive regex and then subtract the matches from the original text, but I'm looking for a more 'elegant' solution.

thx for any help

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#split` works as negative match. It returns you an array of whatever part that does not match the regex.

```
'XXXXXXXX<em>YYYYYYY</em>ZZZZZZZZ'.split(%r|<em>.*?</em>|)
# => ['XXXXXXX', 'ZZZZZZZZ']
```

And if want it back into a string, just do `join`.

```
'XXXXXXXX<em>YYYYYYY</em>ZZZZZZZZ'.split(%r|<em>.*?</em>|).join
 # => 'XXXXXXXZZZZZZZZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing with *lookaround* is that it doesn't consume any of the input. If you want to match everything but a pattern, it means that you want to match the prefix and the suffix of that pattern. To match the suffix, you probably want to consume --- and throw away -- the pattern that you don't want. But negative lookahead doesn't consume.